# Unity: knockback in all directions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, push

I want to make my player bounce in all directions when it collides with my object, I know that when it hit the left side of my object my player gets knock back to the left and the same with the right side, but how can I include the top and bottom of my object. If I'm not making any sense please look at these pictures (X=0 Y=1) and (X=0 Y=-1). (http://noobtuts.com/content/unity/2d-pong-game/vector2_directions.png)

```
 public float xForceToAdd;
 public float yForceToAdd;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {

  }

  // Update is called once per frame
   void Update () {

    }
   void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)  {
     if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
     {
       //Store the vector 2 of the location where the initial hit happened;
       Vector2 initialHitPoint = new Vector2 (other.gameObject.transform.position.x, other.gameObject.transform.position.y);
       float xForce = 0;
       float yForce = 0;
        //Grab our collided with objects rigibody
      Rigidbody2D rigidForForce = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
       //Determine left right center of X hit
       if (initialHitPoint.x > (this.transform.position.x + (this.transform.localScale.x /3)))
        {
         xForce = 1;
       }
       else if (initialHitPoint.x < (this.transform.position.x - (this.transform.localScale.x /3)))
       {
         xForce = -1;
       }
      else
       {
          xForce = 0;
       }
       if (initialHitPoint.y > (this.transform.position.y + (this.transform.localScale.y /3)))
       {
          yForce = 1;
       }
      else if (initialHitPoint.y < (this.transform.position.y - (this.transform.localScale.y /3)))
       {
          yForce = -1;
       }
      else
       {
          yForce = 0;
       }
       rigidForForce.velocity = new Vector2(xForce * xForceToAdd, yForce * yForceToAdd);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)  {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        Vector2 v = other.gameObject.transform.position - this.transform.position;
        //Grab our collided with objects rigibody
        Rigidbody2D rigidForForce = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rigidForForce.velocity = v.normalized;
    }
}
```

Rather than figuring out if you should go up/down/left/right, use the vector math functions.  If you're only interested in pushing in the orthogonal directions, do this for the last line

```
        boolean onX = Mathf.Abs(v.x) > Mathf.Abs(v.y);
        rigidForForce.velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(v.x)*onX?1:0,Mathf.Sign(v.y)*onX?0:1);
```

Comment: Thank you but nothing seems to be happening. And I made sure that isTrigger was checked.

Comment: Can you insert some `Debug.Log` statements to see what the resulting velocity values are? (And to insure that the method is being called)?

Comment: Um how would I do that?

Comment: Thank you the debug.log is working but there is still not force being add

Comment: The whole point of the debug statements is to figure out if the desired value is being returned. If it is, then the problem is elsewhere. Since you didn't tell me what it printed out, I do not know if the value was as desired or not. Put more debug statements in, displaying other values, until you figure out which value isn't the value you want.